# how to search browscap.ini in localhost wamp server

Tags: php

I cant find browscap.ini because of that I can't use get_browser(null, true);

This is my php.ini file

1. [browscap]
   ;http://php.net/browscap
   ;browscap = extra/browscap.ini;

And than I was changed that

2. [browscap]
   ;http://php.net/browscap
   browscap = "C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.5/extra/browscap.ini";

But I am not Ok.. Pls help me..

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one **php.ini** in wamp for different features. In order to edit the php.ini, access it through wamp tray icon.
Have fun.